# Turbo C++ and GCC compiler produces different results during pointer incrementation?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, gcc

The below program is used to calculate the sum of the floating point numbers in an array.

I just modified it using pointer concept by assigning the base address of the array 'a' to the pointer variable 'p' and then incrementing the pointer variable to calculate the sum of the array.

```
int main()
{
    float a[5],*p,sum=0.0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    p=a;
    for(i=0;*p!='\0';i++)
    {
        sum=sum+*p;
        *p++;
    }
    cout<<sum;
    return 0;
}
```

But while compiling this program using a GCC compiler the sum of the array just gets doubled. Why this happens??

NOTE: This problem occurs only with GCC compiler, Turbo C++ produces the correct result.

EDIT: As you guys say that p is not guaranteed to be `0` at the end of the array then how come one compiler(TURBO C++) can able to produce the correct result and the other one (GCC) just doubles it instead of printing some garbage values.

Comment: Your code is wrong, that one compiler gives you the result you expect means nothing. `p` is not guaranteed to to be `0` at the end - you just cannot assume that.

Comment: What is `*p != '\0'` supposed to be testing?

Comment: I tried this type of condition because i want to terminate the loop without using the size of the array .... like how we do in a character array or strings.

Comment: But you are *not* iterating a char array/C-style string. Why would you assume that what holds there holds here?

Comment: As you say that p is not guaranteed to be 0 at the end of the array then how come one compiler(TURBO C++) can able to produce the correct result and the other one (GCC) just doubles it instead of printing some garbage values.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. Next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the wrong loop condition: `*p!='\0'`

This is equivalent to `*p != 0.0f`, but your array is not terminated this way.  The loop will run too long and the program will try to access beyond the bounds of the array, which is an error.  You want `i < 5` instead.  Here is a fixed version of your loop.

```
for (i = 0, p = a; i < 5; i++, p++) {
    sum += *p;
}
```

Any time your code has an error of this kind in it, there is a chance that the error will manifest differently depending on the compiler or settings.

Since this is C++, you can write the array this way instead:

```
for (auto item : a) {
    sum += item;
}
```

Comment: I'd personally go with `const auto&` as the default option - not that it matters here, but "good habits" and all that ;)

Comment: But how can I able to terminate a floating point array if I doesn't know the size of it.

Comment: The range based for loop uses `std::begin` and `std::end` and those work with old-school arrays (using a vector is usually preferable though)..

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I don't consider it a good habit to use `const auto &` as a default option.  It makes sense sometimes but here there is no benefit, and in some cases there are drawbacks.

Comment: Well, it has the advantage of not making a copy and making the variable const so you don't accidentally try to modify it. With "auto foo" you pay for a copy and beginners may be surprised that modifying "foo" (which compiles) doesn't modify the container. So I'm still with `const auto&` as the default option when you don't have a specific reason to do otherwise. But, I know that preferences differ and I'm ok with that (for experienced developers who know what they are doing - defaults are mainly for beginners though).

Comment: @JesperJuhl: You don't always want a reference, and you don't always want a copy.  `const float &` seems a bit over the top to me.  Especially given the number of bugs I've seen where `const T &` is modified unexpectedly, I think it makes no sense at all to consider either one "default".

Comment: @JesperJuhl: But I think this is really, really, not an appropriate discussion to have here.  I really want to shut down these tangential style comments.  Last time I had this discussion someone was arguing in favor of copies instead of references (I had used const references in my sample code), and it gets to be quite a bit of noise that's not even remotely relevant to the question at hand.  Suffice it to say there are a lot of different programming styles for C++, and next time you have a comment about style not related to the question, I would appreciate it if you kept it to yourself.

Comment: Experienced people write "what they want". Beginners need handholding - and I just find `const auto&` to be better generic "hand holding" than any alternative... For experts; no argument. For beginners; that's what we are discussing...

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I think an important question to ask yourself is, "Is this comment contributing to the discussion at hand, or is it an off-topic comment about C++ coding style in general?"

Comment: @JesperJuhl: And as for hand-holding: I've spent many hours and days hunting down bugs caused by `const T &` being used instead of `T`.  I think the habit of using `const T &` comes mostly from people used to C++98, and I don't want to encourage it in the days of C++11.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you assume `p` points to a array where the last(end) element is 0 just like a c-style string.  This assumtion is false.  There is no requirement that there is a 0 at then end of the array.

You need to terminate the loop by using the size of the array or  by comparing to a pointer to the one past the end element.